# Openshift first steps

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

I'm really new about Openshift. I create a new wildfly application, make some change ("helloword" with static html) and push everything. The application build fine and restart, but when I try to access it, I'm always getting the Wildfly's welcome page. Did I miss something? Do I have to install rhc client to see Widlfy's log file?

Comment: You can access the log files using the rhc tail command. What did you change?

Comment: As a new user this book might be of help
https://www.openshift.com/blogs/announcing-a-new-book-getting-started-with-openshift-a-guide-for-impatient-beginners